# Discrete choice questionnaire construction

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to conduct my first Discrete Choice experiment. To do this I have to construct a proper questionnaire to measure consumer preferences in a best possible way.

The experiment concerns measuring Willingness to Pay for air pollution reduction in Warsaw, Poland. There are 4 attributes, respondends will be asked in the questionnaire. The attributes and their levels are below:

1. mortality = [0, 2500, 5000] <- lifes saved in the effect of air pollution reduction
2. morbidity = [0, 250 000, 500 000] <- illnesses prevented in the effect of air pollution reduction
3. visibility improvement (in percentage) = [0, 50, 100] <- visibility improvement in the effect of air pollution reduction
4. ecological tax = [13, 25, 38] <- the price people have to pay to achieve some air pollution reduction

In the questionnaire people will be asked to choose between: A-scenario, B-scenario and Status-Quo. Both scenarios contain levels of attributes, which were desribed above. Using Python, I generated all possible A,B sets. And here is where my issue begins. There are 5184 possible sets.

Is there any algorithm I can use to create a reasonable subset of all this sets? Reasonable, I mean, not to get options like: 
A = [2500, 250 000, 50%, 13]
B = [2500, 250 000, 50%, 25]
So the options, which don't really check preferences, but only reading skills of the respondend.

I hope, I presented my idea rather clear. If not, here is the article, my conception is based on: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479706004002

I will be really grateful for all your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I managed to find the sollution myself. If someone needs a proper tool for such an analysis there is really useful R-package for it.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AlgDesign/AlgDesign.pdf